# Using $ notation in middle of C-Shell statement

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I have a bunch of directories to process, so I start a for loop like this:

```
foreach n (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Then I have a bunch of commands where I am copying over a few files from different places

```
cp file1 dir$n
cp file2 dir$n
```

but I have a couple commands where the $n is in the middle of the command like this:

```
cp -r dir$nstep1 dir$n
```

When I run this command, the shell complains that it cannot find the variable $nstep1. What i want to do is evaluate the $n first and then concatenate the text around it. I tried using `` and (), but neither of those work. How to do this in csh?

Comment: `dir${n}step1` — surround the name with braces.

Comment: Aside: Scripting in csh is generally not considered to be a good idea. See [Top 10 Reasons Not to Use the C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt), or [the author's more recently-updated page on the same topic](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Csh.html); or the classic-but-dated [CSH Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: I c. I have noticed that some of the syntax in csh is a little weird, and some things took a long time to debug. I was just being lazy about changing my default shell when I login to this system, but it sounds like changing my shell to bash will be worthwhile in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this respect behavior is similar to POSIX shells:

```
cp -r "dir${n}step1" "dir${n}"
```

---

The quotes prevent string-splitting and glob expansion. To observe what this means, compare the following:

```
# prints "hello * cruel * world" on one line
set n=" * cruel * "
printf '%s\n' "hello${n}world"
```

...to this:

```
# prints "hello" on one line
# ...then a list of files in the current directory each on their own lines
# ...then "cruel" on another line
# ...then a list of files again
# ... and then "world"
set n=" * cruel * "
printf '%s\n' hello${n}world
```

In real-world cases, correct quoting can thus be the difference between deleting the oddly-named file you're trying to operate on, and deleting everything else in the directory as well.

Comment: Are the quotes necessary?